# Animated page transitions in react

Tags: animation, reactjs, transition

The past couple of weeks I've been working on an app using React. So far everything is working fine, but now I want to add some transitions to it. These transitions are a bit more complex than any examples I managed to find.

I've got 2 pages, an overview and a detail page which I'd like to transition between.

I'm using react-router to manage my routes:

```
<Route path='/' component={CoreLayout}>

  <Route path=':pageSlug' component={Overview} />
  <Route path=':pageSlug/:detailSlug' component={DetailView} />

</Route>
```

Overview looks like this:
[image]

Detailview looks like this:
[image]

The idea of the transition is that you click on one of the elements of the Overview. This element which has been clicked moves towards the position it should have on the detailView. The transition should be initiated by a route change (I think) and should also be able to happen in reverse.

I've already tried using `ReactTransitionGroup` on the Layout, which has a render method which looks like this:

```
render () {
    return (
        <div className='layout'>
            <ReactTransitionGroup>
                React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { key: this.props.location.pathname })
            </ReactTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This will give the child component the ability to receive the special [lifecycle hooks](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup). But I'd like to access the child components somehow during these hooks and still keep doing things the React way.

Could someone point me in the right direction for the next step to take? Or maybe point me to an example which I may have missed somewhere? In previous projects I used [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) together with [liquid fire](http://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/) to get these kinds of transitions, is there maybe something like this for React?

I'm using [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/)/[react-redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux)/[react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)/[react-router-redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-redux).

Comment: you can use the greensock animation library with the lifecycle hooks to make some really cool transitions.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I tried to implement something like this and came up with a very basic solution, but it works. I got inspired by Androids Shared Element Transitions and the implementation in exponentjs/ex-navigation (React Native). It would be good to know if you found a good and reusable solution to this before I'm posting my stuff.

Comment: FYI react-router v4 (still in alpha, maybe beta) has done away with the custom lifecycle hooks and simply uses the standard component lifecycle hooks, which might let you do what you are trying to do

Comment: hey @tommy , I'm looking to do similar transitions too! Do you mind sharing a small snippet on how you achieved it?

Comment: @sammkj Just did, tell me what you think ;-)

Comment: @tommy, thanks! I will do an experiment with it! =)

Comment: I'm hosting an example app, see my updated answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Edit: Added a working example***

https://lab.award.is/react-shared-element-transition-example/

(Some issues in Safari for macOS for me)

---

The idea is to have the elements to be animated wrapped in a container that stores its positions when mounted. I created a simple React Component called `SharedElement` that does exactly this.

So step by step for your example (`Overview` view and `Detailview`):

1. The `Overview` view gets mounted. Each *item* (the squares) inside the Overview is wrapped in the `SharedElement` with a unique ID (for example *item-0*, *item-1* etc). The `SharedElement` component stores the position for each item in a static `Store` variable (by the ID you gave them).
2. You navigate to the `Detailview`. The Detailview is wrapped into another `SharedElement` that has the same ID as the item you clicked on, so for example *item-4*.
3. Now this time, the SharedElement sees that an item with the same ID is already registered in its store. It will clone the new element, apply the old elements position to it (the one from the Detailview) and animates to the new position (I did it using GSAP). When the animation has completed, it overwrites the new position for the item in the store.

Using this technique, it's actually independent from React Router (no special lifecycle methods but `componentDidMount`) and it will even work when landing on the Overview page first and navigating to the Overview page.

I will share my implementation with you, but be aware that it has some known bugs. E.g. you have to deal with z-indeces and overflows yourself; and it doesn't handle *unregistering* element positions from the store yet. I'm pretty sure if someone can spend some time on this, you can make a great little plugin out of it.

The implementation:

*index.js*

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import Overview from './Overview'
import DetailView from './DetailView'

import "./index.css";

import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

const routes = (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Overview} />
            <Route path="detail/:id" component={DetailView} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(
    routes,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

*App.js*

```js
import React, {Component} from "react"
import "./App.css"

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

*Overview.js* - Note the ID on the SharedElement

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Overview.css'
import items from './items' // Simple array containing objects like {title: '...'}
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import SharedElement from './SharedElement'

export default class Overview extends Component {

    showDetail = (e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        hashHistory.push(`/detail/${id}`)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Overview">
                {items.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="ItemOuter" key={`outer-${index}`}>
                            <SharedElement id={`item-${index}`}>
                                <a
                                    className="Item"
                                    key={`overview-item`}
                                    onClick={e => this.showDetail(e, index + 1)}
                                >
                                    <div className="Item-image">
                                        <img src={require(`./img/${index + 1}.jpg`)} alt=""/>
                                    </div>

                                    {item.title}
                                </a>
                            </SharedElement>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

*DetailView.js* - Note the ID on the SharedElement

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './DetailItem.css'
import items from './items'
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import SharedElement from './SharedElement'

export default class DetailView extends Component {

    getItem = () => {
        return items[this.props.params.id - 1]
    }

    showHome = e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        hashHistory.push(`/`)
    }

    render() {
        const item = this.getItem()

        return (
            <div className="DetailItemOuter">
                <SharedElement id={`item-${this.props.params.id - 1}`}>
                    <div className="DetailItem" onClick={this.showHome}>
                        <div className="DetailItem-image">
                            <img src={require(`./img/${this.props.params.id}.jpg`)} alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        Full title: {item.title}
                    </div>
                </SharedElement>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

*SharedElement.js*

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes, cloneElement } from 'react'
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom'
import TweenMax, { Power3 } from 'gsap'

export default class SharedElement extends Component {

    static Store = {}
    element = null

    static props = {
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
        duration: PropTypes.number,
        delay: PropTypes.number,
        keepPosition: PropTypes.bool,
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        duration: 0.4,
        delay: 0,
        keepPosition: false,
    }

    storeNewPosition(rect) {
        SharedElement.Store[this.props.id] = rect
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Figure out the position of the new element
        const node = findDOMNode(this.element)
        const rect = node.getBoundingClientRect()
        const newPosition = {
            width: rect.width,
            height: rect.height,
        }

        if ( ! this.props.keepPosition) {
            newPosition.top = rect.top
            newPosition.left = rect.left
        }

        if (SharedElement.Store.hasOwnProperty(this.props.id)) {
            // Element was already mounted, animate
            const oldPosition = SharedElement.Store[this.props.id]

            TweenMax.fromTo(node, this.props.duration, oldPosition, {
                ...newPosition,
                ease: Power3.easeInOut,
                delay: this.props.delay,
                onComplete: () => this.storeNewPosition(newPosition)
            })
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(() => { // Fix for 'rect' having wrong dimensions
                this.storeNewPosition(newPosition)
            }, 50)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return cloneElement(this.props.children, {
            ...this.props.children.props,
            ref: element => this.element = element,
            style: {...this.props.children.props.style || {}, position: 'absolute'},
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar problem, where I had a search bar and wanted it to move and wrap to a different size and place on a specific route (like a general search in the navbar and a dedicated search page). For that reason, I created a component very similar to SharedElement above.

The component expects as props, a `singularKey` and a `singularPriority` and than you render the component in serval places, but the component will only render the highest priority and animate to it.

The component is on `npm` as `react-singular-compoment`
And here is the [GitHub page for the docs](https://github.com/dor6/SingularComponent).